# Use wildcard in dnsmasq override address

Tags: dnsmasq

I'm setting up dnsmasq and I want all com.*.svc.cluster.local addresses to return NXDOMIAN. I tried setting ' --address=/com.*.svc.cluster.local/ but wildcards don't work. Is there any way to get around it? The list of domains is long and growing so I would love to use * instead of spell each one out.